# Exoplayer video frames moves forward in pause state in api<23

Tags: java, android, video, exoplayer2.x

I an using `exoplayer` in `recyclerview`. All my video are in `recyclerview` is in pause mode. So Video postion should remain same  when I come back to same video after scrolling.
But in my case video frames moves forward  when I come back to same video after scrolling.This happens in api lower then marshmallow(23)

I an using library  `'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.4'`

Here my adapter bind data of viewholder code:

```
  public class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View parent;
    SimpleExoPlayer player;
    VideoSurfaceView videoSurfaceView;
    private DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector;
    private int mainHandler;
    private MediaSource mediaSource;

    public VideoViewHolder(final View v) {
        super(v);
        parent = v;
        imgAudio = v.findViewById(R.id.imgAudio);
        videoSurfaceView = v.findViewById(R.id.exo_player);
        aspectRatioFrameLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.control_frame);
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position == -1)
                    return;
                VideoUri videoUri = videoInfoList.get(position);
                if (videoUri == null)
                    return;
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, PlayrtActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("videoUri", videoUri);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    void bindData(int position) {
        if (position == -1)
            return;
        VideoUri videoUri = videoInfoList.get(position);
        if (videoUri == null)
            return;
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory =
                new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);

        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory);
        @DefaultRenderersFactory.ExtensionRendererMode int extensionRendererMode =
                DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_OFF;
        DefaultRenderersFactory renderersFactory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(context,
                null, extensionRendererMode);

        LoadControl loadControl =
                new DefaultLoadControl(new DefaultAllocator(true, C.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE), 5000, 10000, 2500, 5000);

            if (player == null) {
                player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(renderersFactory, trackSelector,loadControl);
                MediaSourceBuilder mediaSourceBuilder = new MediaSourceBuilder(context, videoUri.getUri());
                mediaSource = mediaSourceBuilder.build();


                player.prepare(mediaSource);
                player.setVideoSurfaceView(videoSurfaceView);
                player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your videos are getting recycled (removed from memory). So, you need to save the videos position and add an *onStart* listener to the player that seek to that position.